# Post an MVC model with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Can I post an MVC model using AJAX, like:

```
 $.ajax ({
     //what elements are important?
     data: '@Model.Product',
     success: function(data){
        $("#divProducts").html(data);
     }
 }
```

I want to avoid changing the model into JSON or JavaScript objects because I would still have to load them from the fields on the page.  It would be easier if I use the standard @Html.TextboxFor stuff to fill the model fields and then post the whole model with AJAX.

Comment: yes. you certainly can do that.

Comment: @DanielA.White How can I do that?  Just the way I've listed?

Comment: theres plenty of examples out there.

Comment: You question is not clear. Posting back `@Model` would only post back the original model (a bit pointless). If you mean post back you form values then you can use the jquery [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method

Comment: @StephenMuecke - so the model as it has changed with values or text fields in the form would not be reflected in the ajax post of data?

Comment: Not if your used `@Model` because razor code is parsed on the server. Check the html generated by `var myModel = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Product))');` - its the original model and the value of `myModel` does not change just because you change the value in a text box. You need to serialize the form and post that back using ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is to not use the JSON.Encode method but to simply fill the loaded model with values and then use $.serializeArray() with the class of the fields you want to load the model with.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the model into JSON and then post the serialized JSON object to server.

```
var productModel= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Product))
$.ajax ({
     //send the serialized JSON 
     data: JSON.stringify(productModel),
     success: function(data){
        $("#divProducts").html(data);
     }
 }
```

Comment: That would be rather pointless - its just posting back exactly the same values (unchanged) that were sent to the view in the first place.